# Permission change based on file extension using ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to change the permission of the file based on it's extension using ansible, for example I have directory `test` and within this directory I have a lot of shell script(.sh) and python(.py) files. I want to change the permission of shell script to 0700 and python files to 0644. Can you please help me that how I can achieve this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. This should work. Tweak it to your needs.

```
  - file: path={{item}} mode=0644
    with_fileglob:
        - <full_path>/*.py
  - file: path={{item}} mode=0700
    with_fileglob:
        - <full_path>/*.sh
```

If the files are on remote, do this:

```
  - shell: ls /test/*.py
    register: py_files

  - file: path={{item}} mode=0644
    with_items: py_files.stdout_lines
```

Comment: I have tested it but it skipped the tasks GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [ansible-test]

TASK: [file path={{item}} mode=0640] ******************************************
skipping: [ansible-test]

TASK: [file path={{item}} mode=0700] ******************************************
skipping: [ansible-test]

Comment: Can you post your play? It is possible you are not specifying the filepath correctly. I tried it before posting the solution.

Comment: here is my playbook and I am using ansible 1.9.4: ---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - file: path={{item}} mode=0644
      with_fileglob:
        - /test/*.py
    - file: path={{item}} mode=0700
      with_fileglob:
        - /test/*.sh

Comment: @arbabnazar updated the solution for remote machines